# Edit view not being populated with objects data

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

I am quite new to ASP .Net, and could use some help... I have an ASP .Net Core 1.1 web app. In it, I have an "Edit" view for editing a simple object, which a corresponding controller calls when routed to it. This is the view:

```
@model InspectionsTestClient.Models.Property

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary();

<form asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Property</h4>
        <hr />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UnitNumber" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="UnitNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UnitNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="BuildingName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="BuildingName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BuildingName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Street" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input asp-for="Street" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Street" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

This is the controller which calls that view:

```
// GET: Property/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And this is the model:

```
namespace InspectionsTestClient.Models
{
    //[Table("property")]
    public class Property
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Unit number too long")]
        [Display(Name = "Unit #")]
        public string UnitNumber { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(45, ErrorMessage = "BuildingName name too long")]
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(45, ErrorMessage = "Street too long")]
        public string Street { get; set; }
    }

}
```

So when I navigate to that page, the controller fires up, and returns the Edit view. I have confirmed the parameter "id" is populated. When the Edit view loads in the browser, however, all the input textboxes are empty. I would expect them to be pre-populated with the values for the object in question. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is happening because you are not returning that object to the view.. actually in your case you're not even going out to the db to get the object.

You need to edit you `Edit` action to something like this:

```
// GET: Property/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var object = db.TableName.Find(id);

    // db = connectionstring
    // TableName = database table that holds the object that you want to return

    if (object == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(object);
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
   public class PropertyController
   {
      private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
      public PropertyController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext){
           _dbContext = dbContext;
      }

     //GET: Property/Edit/5
      public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
      {
           var property = await _dbContext.Property.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
           return View(property);
       }
    }
```

If you don't pull the data from the database and send it to the view of course it will always be blank.  `Edit(int id)` there will be 2, both slightly different from the other.

```
   [HttpPost]       
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   //Post: Property/Edit/5
   public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id", "UnitNumber", "BuildingNumber", "Street")] Property property)
  {   
     if(ModelState.IsValid){



      }
      else{

     }
  }
```

not everyting is present but that is part of your adventure.